# Can I get a return value in some way from a dbms_scheduler job?

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing, oracle10g

I have a webpage (generated via PL/SQL) that allows someone to toggle a remote device on or off.  They are presented with a list of devices and they use checkboxes to select the ones to toggle.  UTL_HTTP is used to communicate with the devices.  Currently, the devices are toggled serially.  Once all have been toggled, an email is sent to the user.  Depending on how many devices are selected, doing this serially has the potential to take too long.  So I'm looking at using DBMS_SCHEDULER to execute the toggling in parallel.

The problem is that the toggling process returns a status, either 'OK' or the reason it failed.  I need that result to include in the email to the user.  So, I need the 'main' procedure to create the SCHEDULER jobs and then wait for them to finish (and somehow get their statuses) before sending an email to the user.

Is this possible, short of having each job write it's status to a table which is polled by the 'main' process?  I've read references to DBMS_PIPE for inter-process communication, but haven't found a good example (ie, one that makes sense to me) showing how to do it.

Comment: Look into [`DBMS_AQ`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_aq.htm#ARPLS100) as well...

Comment: You *could* pass some information by raising an exception and reading it from `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`.  But that would be much uglier than writing to a table.

Comment: I ended up having each job write it's status to a table and had the main process poll that table until all the jobs had finished.  Not sure I should post that as the "answer" though.

Comment: I think it's worth having that as an answer.  In the future, if anyone wants to get a return value from dbms_scheduler it will be useful to know that the answer is "No, it can't be done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a way to do it, I couldn't figure it out.  I ended up having each job write it's status to a table.  The main process knows how many individual jobs were created and polls the table to tell when all jobs are finished (or it timesout after a specified amount of time has passed, in case one of the jobs dies for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

## An Alternate Solution to Watching Parallel Processes Run Through DBMS_SCHEDULER Jobs

### New Edit: An Abbreviated Discussion of the Core Problem

(Edit: 03/10/2014) I added this discussion after some helpful feedback from one of the posters watching this thread.

> **Opening Comments**:  Other discussion threads here mention the use of some output value from the function call itself.  This is not natively possible with the existing `DBMS_SCHEDULER` features.
>
> There are no `OUT` type parameter values or function outputs related to notifying a condition encountered by the procedure invoked.  The most immediate problem at hand is: *How do we run a series of related tasks via PL/SQL stored procedure in parallel?* (i.e., without waiting for one another to finish before each start themselves.)

Whatever invokes the procedure tasks should not wait around for a status output.  The response time is likely to be widely variable and whatever calls the procedure in this way would also hang.  Associated processes would be waiting for the completion of the procedure or the return of a specified output.

> **A Suggested Approach**:  Other comments on this problem are on the right track.  Have the custom output written to a table where it can be queried later when a response is ready.  If you really want to make this a hands-off task, try putting a trigger on the output table.  Every time a message of a specific value (representing a completed state of the request) is populated, invoke a procedure with Oracle's Mail package that sends out your notification email.

### How to Track Your Invoked Jobs By Understanding `DBMS_SCHEDULER` Features

Using a scheduled job is a good way of initiating and watching a set of procedure calls that are not sequentially dependent on one another.  I have been able to accomplish a similar approach using the original **DBMS_JOB** functionality of previous versions of the Oracle database.

> **A Case Study:**  Using a web-based application interface (Oracle Application Express) I had a project which allowed the user to initiate a resource-intensive series of database operations.  Initiating the request was all that was needed.
>
> **The Actual Use Scenario:**  The user didn't need to wait around for its completion.  The problem was that wiring the web request form directly to a call to this database package and its procedures also tied down control of the form and its session making the user "wait" for the procedure itself to complete.

Firing off a scheduled job that invoked this process separated the interaction with the web page from the wait for the actual process to complete.  Scheduling a job task was almost instantaneous, so the wait between the submission of the request and return of control back to the web page also had a negligible wait.

### Using Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER: An Introduction to the Approach

**The Current Problem and Solution Under Discussion**:   Use the native **DBMS_SCHEDULER** status views to monitor the progress of your process. There are many, but **ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG** is the simpler of the collection and is a good start to what we're trying to accomplish.

1. Use an easily identifiable name for each job... and also each job that may be related to one another.
2. Initiate an additional job to watch all the parallel tasks until the last one is completed.  Alter this "watching" job to end once this condition has been met.

### The Basic Syntax to Initiate a Database Job on Scheduler

The procedure [**DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_sched.htm#999617) creates a job in a single call without using an existing program or schedule:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             IN VARCHAR2,
   job_type             IN VARCHAR2,
   job_action           IN VARCHAR2,
   number_of_arguments  IN PLS_INTEGER              DEFAULT 0,
   start_date           IN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL,
   repeat_interval      IN VARCHAR2                 DEFAULT NULL,
   end_date             IN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL,
   job_class            IN VARCHAR2                 DEFAULT 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
   enabled              IN BOOLEAN                  DEFAULT FALSE,
   auto_drop            IN BOOLEAN                  DEFAULT TRUE,
   comments             IN VARCHAR2                 DEFAULT NULL);
```

***These are the input parameters that you should pay close attention to:***

- **job_name**   You can leave it to default, or you can help organize your job requests by using a consistent naming convention.  JOB_NAME is a special parameter because it has a helper function called *GENERATE_JOB_NAME*, where you can specify a naming prefix to combine with the internal name assignment.  This isn't absolutely necessary, but it helps.

  ```
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.GENERATE_JOB_NAME 
      (prefix IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'JOB$_') RETURN VARCHAR2;
  ```

  An example call within the create_job definition:

  ```
  job_name => dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name( prefix => 'MY_EXAMPLE_JOB_')
  ```

  So in the example above, we could have a series of jobs with names like:  MY_EXAMPLE_JOB_0001, MY_EXAMPLE_JOB_0002, MY_EXAMPLE_JOB_0003...
- **job_type**   This one is straight from the Oracle documentation.  Most likely it will be the type: *plsql_block* (The value may also be case sensitive).
- **repeat_interval**   Do not set this value for your one-time parallel tasks.  The job will identify itself as completed once the referenced stored procedure reaches completion, or errors out.
- **end_date**   Leave this null or unassigned as well.  This value does not apply for a one-time execution of the procedure it is watching.
- **start_date**   Leave this null or unassigned as well.  No value means to initiate the specified job as soon as the job is *ENABLED*.
- **enabled**   Defaulted to *FALSE* you will need to set this to *TRUE* as soon as you create the job, or when you're ready to initiate the process "thread".
- **auto_drop**   This is an important one.  The rest of this method depends on the meta data of each job remaining in the DBMS_SCHEDULER's log tables even after they have hit an exception or reached completion.  Set this to *FALSE*.
- **job_action**   This will vary depending on the number of parallel processes you initiate.  First, you should initiate the first of your parallel processes... and also the related "Monitoring" process that will be active for a specific request.  Job actions for a **plsql_block** type job looks something like this:

  Example PL/SQL Block:
  BEGIN my_procedure(a, b, c); END;

### Creating a Job Monitoring Process

Part of the problem you encountered is that DBMS_SCHEDULER may watch a process of varying execution time, but it's not very good at letting you know when it's done or if it encountered an exception.

Your "watcher" process just needs to be another scheduled job that queries the [**ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2044.htm#REFRN20347) table for the procedures it's responsible for, and figures out if all of them have reached the desired closing status.

> Assumption: For a given request, you will know the number of parallel processes (remotely initiated switching events) required to complete this type of request... all the processes do not have to start exactly at the same time, but the watcher will need to know it still has to wait, even if all the related processes it can see have matched its criteria as "completed".

The kinds of tasks your "watching" procedure will need to include:

```
WATCHING SQL Criteria Example:

WITH   MONITOR_QUERY AS (
       SELECT COUNT(LOG_ID) AS COMPLETED_PROCESS_COUNT
         FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG
        WHERE JOB_NAME LIKE '001-REQUEST%')

SELECT CASE WHEN COMPLETED_PROCESS_COUNT = <TOTAL_PROCESSES>
            THEN 'DONE' ELSE 'IN-PROGRESS' END as REQUEST_STATUS
  FROM MONITOR_QUERY
```

Also note that when you call the job that runs the monitoring process, you may find it useful to generate a unique job name ahead of time before kicking off its repeating job (should be done only once per request or set of parallel jobs):

```
DECLARE
   who_am_i   VARCHAR2(65);

BEGIN
   SELECT dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name
     INTO who_am_i
     FROM DUAL;

   --
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (job_name => who_am_i,
     job_type => 'plsql_block',
     job_action => 'BEGIN my_monitoring_task(p_1, p_2, who_am_i); END',
     repeat_interval => 300,
     comments => 'Interval time units are defaulted to SECONDS';
     ...);

END;
```

This job is most effective if it is created at the same time or shortly after the first parallel job in the series is launched.

### When The Monitored Request is Completed

When the selection criteria is met (i.e., all related processes are closed in some way) then it's time to fire off your notification and also to stop the watcher for this request.

```
Stopping the Monitoring Job

DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB (
   job_name         IN VARCHAR2
   force            IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE);
```

- **job_name**   If you used a custom naming scheme for each job you initiate, you could also store this value as an input parameter into your watcher procedure call.  The watcher would then know how to shut itself off when it's done.  Remember, if you use the GENERATE_JOB_NAME function call, you are only specifying the prefix to the entire job_name used in the scheduler.
- **force**   Set this one to *FALSE* (The default) or leave it unspecified.  It is better to let Oracle find a way to gracefully put your watcher job to a halt.

### Closing Thoughts and Comments

If the outcome or completion of several of your procedures are related, an additional scheduled job can be repeated as a monitoring "heartbeat" to check if all the dependencies for a discrete process have been met.

> A comment on clean-up:  This design requires the *auto_drop* parameter set as FALSE.  A daily or weekly process could also be scheduled to issue a *drop_job* command that will clean up the scheduler's logs of records related to completed and reported requests.

You can also see, by including the invoking *job_name* within the scheduled job itself, you can provide the procedure(s) contained within it the ability to turn itself off once the right conditions have been met.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  It's not just about how to run jobs, but how to get values from them.

Comment: @jonearles: Scheduled jobs are a viable solution... partway down the solution, I identify the job scheduler log view and how to query it to  identify the status of the procedure call contained within it.

Comment: Yes, but that will only tell you if the job is finished.  It won't let you return a custom value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I recapped a few additional explanations at the top of my solution to clarify.  If you have time to read, you will see we're talking about the same thing in some ways:  `DBMS_SCHEDULER` does not have an output value.  Writing to an external table is the way to record custom feedback/exceptions/warnings/announcements from the procedures that were called.  Scheduler's meta log tables also hold info so watch out from starting a redundant effort.  My discussion of jobs addressed the concept of running multiple instances of the same procs from a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Queues to the rescue.
Slave sessions (jobs), when they are ready, put their return values into an AQ (practically any data structure is allowed).
The coordinator session, which initiated the slaves, listens on the queue and gathers the return values.
Actually, AQs are the recommended way for intersession communication in Oracle anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c the column [ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS.OUTPUT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E87CA539-38E8-41A4-B10B-784308A56F02.htm#REFRN20386) can be used to return values from a job.

For example, create a job and write output using `DBMS_OUTPUT`:

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name => 'TEST_JOB',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => q'[begin dbms_output.put_line('Test output'); end; ]',
        enabled => true
    );
end;
/
```

Now read the output:

```
select job_name, to_char(log_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') log_date, output
from all_scheduler_job_run_details
where owner  = user
    and job_name = 'TEST_JOB'
order by log_date desc;

JOB_NAME   LOG_DATE     OUTPUT
--------   --------     -------
TEST_JOB   2017-12-26   Test output
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to use oracle version 11, you might use the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE pl/sql package, which does what you want. If you cannot upgrade, then you can implement some c callouts from pl/sql which provide similar functionality.

If you decide to use dbms_pipe and you are using the RAC database option be aware that using DBMS_PIPE has its limitations for failover.

Comment: v11 isn't an option; stuck on 10g.